# Link a sting from one spreadsheet to number in another spreadsheet (Excel)

Tags: string, excel, formula, spreadsheet

I have two excel spreadsheets named sheet1 and sheet2. Sheet2 is a sheet that contains two columns in which the information in column A needs to be related to column B. In sheet A, if i put in something that comes from sheet2, column A, I need Sheet2 Column B to pop up in the next cell. How do I do this? Thanks

example (the colons between A and B represent new columns):
Sheet1
A:B
Pizza:"10 should show up here automatically"

Sheet2
tuna:2
Pizza:10

Comment: That worked, I just didnt know where to begin looking and everything i found was using INDIRECT and some others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the below in B1 and drag it to all cells in B column:

```
IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0))
```